# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routeFilterProvider <- routeFilter (coffeescript)

Tags: angularjs, routes, coffeescript, minifiedjs

Basically I want to create routes for my angular app from a CMS without a deployment.  So I am trying to do something similar to this tutorial:  http://gonzalo123.com/2014/06/30/setting-up-states-from-a-json-file-in-angularjs-applications/.   Essentially I have json document that has a list of available routes, and I want to be able to access those routes by name.  This is what I have:
newco.js:

```
@newco = angular.module 'newco', [
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngIdle',
  'LocalStorageModule',
  'checklist-model',
#  'zj.namedRoutes',
  'ng.deviceDetector',
  'noCAPTCHA',
  'feature-flags',
  'ui.router',
  'Routing'
]

@newco.config(['$provide', '$locationProvider','$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'routerProvider', ($provide, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, routerProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('localeInterceptor');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'
  routerProvider.setCollectionUrl
  return

  $stateProvider.state '/',
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: '/pages/home/index-v3'
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/home'
  routerProvider.setCollectionUrl
  return
]).controller 'NewHomeController', ($scope, router) ->
  $scope.reload = ->
    router.setUpRoutes()
    return
  return
```

routing.js.coffee:

```
angular.module('Routing', [ 'ui.router' ]).provider('router', ($stateProvider) ->
  urlCollection = undefined

  @$get = ($http, $state, CMSS3Url) ->
    { setUpRoutes: ->
      $http.get(CMSS3Url + '/routes.json').success (collection) ->
        _.each collection.routes, (route) ->
          $stateProvider.state route,
            url: route
            templateUrl: '/pages/home/new_index'
            controller: 'NewHomeController'
        return
      return
    }

  @setCollectionUrl = (url) ->
    urlCollection = url
    return

  return
).run (router) ->
  router.setUpRoutes()
  return
```

collection:

```
{
  "routes": [
    "/route1",
    "/route2",
    "/"

  ]
}
```

Because I converted from plain js to coffee I am thinking it could be a minification issue but I honestly don't know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be `$routerProvider` instead of `routerProvider`, Also there is no need to include `ngRoute` & `ui.router` to routing engine at same time.you should use either one of them,,

Comment: When I change that I get: " Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routerProvider"

Comment: I'd say, there is not need to use two route engine at same time..use `ui.router` which has good feature than the `ngRoute`

Comment: I am still getting "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routerProvider"  even after removing the ngRoute